# Specify file provider for RazorViewEngine in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm having a solution with an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application project and a WebJob (console application)
Both applications are using a common library project where I have `IRazorViewToStringRenderer` service with views. I want to reuse this service in both applications, WebApp and WebJob. My solution is based on this sample https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/master/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/Program.cs

Here is how I use it:

```
   var viewToStringEngine = ServiceProvider.GetService<IRazorViewToStringRenderer>();
   string htmlContent = await viewToStringEngine.RenderToStringAsync<MyView>("~/Views/MyView.cshtml", new MyView());
```

The problem is `RazorViewEngineOptions` doesn't have anymore the option to specify the file provider ( in ASP.NET Core 6 )

```
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Clear();
        options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider);
    });
```

`IRazorViewToStringRenderer` service is working fine when is called from the Web App, but is not working from the WebJob. It is only working if the WebJob services contains an   IWebHostEnvironment with the `ApplicationName` as the name of the project where IRazorViewToStringRenderer is implemented, otherwise the views cannot be found.

How to specify file provider for the RazorViewEngine ? ( [github sample](https://github.com/Alin764/RazorTest) )

**WebJob service configuration:**

```
private static ServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    var applicationEnvironment = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
    services.AddSingleton(applicationEnvironment);

    services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment>(new WebJobHostEnvironment
    {
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name,
        //ApplicationName = typeof(IRazorViewToStringRenderer).Assembly.GetName().Name,
    });

    var listener = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
    services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticListener>(listener);
    services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(listener);
    services.AddSingleton<ObjectPoolProvider, DefaultObjectPoolProvider>();
    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>(sp => new LoggerFactory());

    services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine();

    services.AddCommonRazorEngine(Configuration);

    return services;
}
```

**RazorServiceCollectionExtension.cs**

```
public static class RazorServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static void AddCommonRazorEngine(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //var fileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(RazorViewToStringRenderer).Assembly);

        // FileProviders property is not available anymore           
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            //options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider);
        });

        services.AddScoped<IRazorViewToStringRenderer, RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
    }
}
```

##### Edit

For others searching a similar solution, I updated my [github sample](https://github.com/Alin764/RazorTest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this problem myself, and it appears that the functionality has been moved to an external package. I was able to work around this by following the instructions located here and then amending them for my purposes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

I.e. install the package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation

Then you can change the appropriate file provider by using the code:

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProviders.Clear();
    options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider);
});
```

Comment: Please note that it does warn that "Runtime compilation isn't supported for Razor components of Blazor apps"

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked in my solution after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation. Another missing piece was to set build action to embedded resource for *.cshtml files.

Comment: How to use this with dependency injected file provider?